# JSP How can I get a Hashmap Value from an ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, hashmap

I am using JSP on a Tomcat server and have read the contents on an INI file and placed them into an ArrayList of Hashmaps. When I loop through them the results look like the following;

-- INI File --

> [General]
>  item0=0
>  item1=1
>  item2=2
>  item3=3
>   item4=4
>
> [Specific]
>  item0=5
>  item1=6
>  item2=7
>  item3=8
>   item4=9

-- My Results --

```
{General={item0=0, item1=1, item2=2, item3=3, item4=4}}<br>
{Specific={item0=5, item1=6, item2=7, item3=8, item4=9}}<br>
```

---

Unfortunately, the server is running a limited version of Tomcat and is on an intranet with no access to the internet, so I cannot use JSTL, and company policy does not allow me to install JavaBeans.

Is there a way to get a specific value from these results without JSTL or JavaBeans?

i.e. Retrieving item2 from General should return 2 and item2 from Specific should return 7.

Also if possible, can I change the value of an item and cycle though the list to update the ini file?

Comment: Although its helpful to have the data, this question could be improved if you also showed your code.  For instance, you can certainly use JSTL on an intranet, but its hard to know what your issue is exactly at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your model to include some sort of SettingsIni class that would contain all the settings from one ini file. This class would have a title member perhaps taken from the ini's filename and has an internal Map to hold the settings' keys and values.

You should include public methods to expose and cast the stored values into their data types. Methods such as `getInt(String key)` and `getBoolean(String key)` that will validate the stored data and return it or a default value on failure.

You could opt to extend this class and add convenience methods to access the settings for known ini files.

```
public class GeneralSettingsIni extends SettingsIni {
    private static String FILEPATH = "file.ini";
    private static String KEY_ITEM0 = "item0";
    public GeneralSettingsIni() {
        super(filepath);
    }

    public int getItem0() {
        return super.getInt(KEY_ITEM0);
    }
    ...
}
```